# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method - subquery count

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, subquery

Hi this question has been asked before but I'm struggling to find an answer that matches my question (the error comes up a lot).

This looks to be similar but with 4 years ago has there been any progress.
[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316615/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32)

Basically I want to move a subquery that returns a count into a function anyway here's the code.

```
vm.SicknessEpisodes = _db.SicknessEpisodes.Where(x => x.Status == true && x.LastDay == null).OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstDay).
                Select(x => new HomeSicknessEpisode
                {
                    SicknessEpisode = x,
                    EpisodesIn12Months = _db.SicknessEpisodes.Where(y => y.StaffID == x.StaffID && y.Status == true &&
                         (y.LastDay == null || (y.LastDay.HasValue && y.LastDay >= prevDate))).Count()
                }).
                ToPagedList(p, 100);
```

This works

This

```
vm.SicknessEpisodes = _db.SicknessEpisodes.Where(x => x.Status == true && x.LastDay == null).OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstDay).
                Select(x => new HomeSicknessEpisode
                {
                    SicknessEpisode = x,
                    EpisodesIn12Months = _db.episodes12Months(x,prevDate).Count()

                }).
                ToPagedList(p, 100);

public IQueryable<SicknessEpisode> episodes12Months(SicknessEpisode x, DateTime prevDate)
        {

            return this.SicknessEpisodes.Where(y => y.StaffID == x.StaffID && y.Status == true &&
                         (y.LastDay == null || (y.LastDay.HasValue && y.LastDay >= prevDate)));


        }
```

Does not.

Can anyone tell me how I can make it work - ideally without going into a List and then foreach each episode to run the count.

I'm just trying to make it as efficient as possible for Entity Framework.
If it's not possible - then that's fine - one of those things.

Comment: Do you *understand* why the second example can't work? `_db.episodes12Months` is *embedded* in an expression that EF tries to translate into SQL. The method call doesn't have a SQL equivalent. When called *in isolation*, `episodes12Months` will run.

Comment: Yeah, is that just a limitation of entity framework - or is there anyway to make that work?

Comment: Limitation? How would you implement it if you were developing EF? Decompile the source code? It cannot execute your method and also have no idea what is inside it in order to be able to translate it to SQL. Encapsulation is not for `IQueryable`s which  translation is based on pure **knowledge*, i.e. known set of methods. The only way you can sort of reuse pieces is to provide them as **expressions**, but this also is not supported out of the box (by C# compiler) and requires 3rd party packages like LINQKit.

Comment: thanks that's fine.

Comment: that linkkit looks useful